# facing issues in extracting elements using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract elements from multiple pages using beautifulsoup. However I observed for same element, class value changes on different pages. Although value is same mostly but some part is suffixed at end. Is there way I can search a part of class value like contains function works.

```
 E1  soup.find('div',{'class':'pv-entity__summary-info pv-ent`enter code here`ity__summary-info--background-section'})
 E2  soup.find('div',{'class':'pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2'})
```

Comment: Please show the code you have already tried and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the class name starts with "pv-entity".you can use Regular Expression

```
soup.find('div',{'class':re.compile(r'pv-entity')})
```